# UWP conventions with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, uwp

I have created a sample UWP project and added Caliburn.Micro 3.0 beta1 to it based on [this tutorial](http://liftcodeplay.com/2015/08/27/windows-10-uwp-caliburn-micro-and-splitview/).

Using the SplitView, I could add a new ViewModel when a Pane button is pressed:

**ShellView**

```
 <Button x:Name="OpenSecondView"
         Margin="24"
         Content="My Second View" />
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
public void OpenSecondView()
{
  _navigationService.For<MainViewModel>().Navigate();
}
```

It loads the proper View (so I presume, conventions are working).

I have a button in the detail view and it has the Name property set.

**MainView**

```
<Button Name="btnStartAction"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
        RelativePanel.Below="btnInformation"
        Style="{StaticResource button}">
```

I added a method in the ViewModel with the same name.

**MainViewModel**

```
public void btnStartAction()
{
  var x = 2;
}
```

Unfortunately when I click it, nothing happens.

What should I set?

**UPDATE**

Well, something strange happened.

If I add the following line in *MainView.xaml.cs*, the button works:

```
public MainView()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

So, it seems that the ViewModel can find its View (hence I can see it) *but* the View has no DataContext.

What should I do?

**UPDATE 2**

This is how the Frame gets registered.

**XAML**

```
 <SplitView.Content>
                <Grid>                  
                <Frame Grid.Row="1"
                           DataContext="{x:Null}"
                           cm:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded] = [SetupNavigationService($source)]" />
                </Grid>
  </SplitView.Content>
```

**ShellModelView**

```
public ShellViewModel(WinRTContainer container)
{
  _container = container;      
}

public void SetupNavigationService(Frame frame)
{
  _navigationService = _container.RegisterNavigationService(frame);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caliburn Micro conventions feature use x:Name directive not Name property.

```
<Button x:Name="btnStartAction"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.Below="btnInformation"
    Style="{StaticResource button}">
```

**Update**

Sorry for giving wrong information, both Name and x:Name can be used for conventions.

**You should register you `MainViewModel` to `WinRTContainer`.**

*App.xaml.cs*

```
public sealed partial class App
{
  private WinRTContainer _container;

  protected override void Configure()
  {
     _container = new WinRTContainer();
     _container.RegisterWinRTServices();

     _container
          .PerRequest<ShellViewModel>()
          .PerRequest<MyFirstViewModel>()
          .PerRequest<MySecondViewModel>()
          .PerRequest<MyThirdViewModel>()
          .PerRequest<MainViewModel>();

     var navigationManager = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();

     navigationManager.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;

  }
}
```

More about simple container see [Simple IoC Container](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/simple-container).

Comment: I tried both (x:Name and Name), they won't work, if I don't set the _DataContext_.

Comment: @Nestor I'm sorry to heard that, it look like ViewModelBinder didn't correspondingly set DataContext of View to ViewModel.  I already tried to add custom ViewModel/View, action binding don't work if I don't register custom ViewModel to WinRTContainer(at Configure method in App.xaml code behind), so did you register your MainViewModel to WinRTContainer? btw, Name work for convention too, sorry to gave you wrong information XD

Comment: How should I register my ViewModel with the WinRTContainer? The XAML has a binding of `RegisterNavigationService` like this:  `<Frame Grid.Row="1"
                           DataContext="{x:Null}"
                           cm:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded] = [SetupNavigationService($source)]" />`. What else should I set?

Comment: @Nestor I already updated answer, I hope you can get it work.

Comment: Yes, that was the missing part. It works now without the explicit initialization. Thanks, I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you decide to implement suspend and restore operations that require cacheing of the viewmodel for later restoration that there will likely be an issue related the ShellView and Window.Current.Contents being set incorrectly to the restored view instead of the ShellView page.  Workaround in the works for this issue.

Comment: What is the proposed solution then?

Comment: Right now there isn't one.  Currently on the table as a potential workaround was checking to see if Window.Current.Content was already set (not null) and to then work out some way to re-init the Frame.  It is untested.